# Why parameter binding of numeric does not work for the Python snowflake connector?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Why do I get SQL compilation error when I tried to use numeric/qmark parameter binding if the numeric/qmark parameters are used right before period (.)?**

### Environment

- Python 3 (3.11)
- pandas==1.3.5
- snowflake-connector-python==2.7.9

### Script

I use the following code to execute my query.

```
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    import snowflake.connector

    snowflake_user = os.getenv("USER")
    snowflake_password = os.getenv("PWD")
    database_name = os.getenv("DATABASE")
    grey_schema_name = os.getenv("SCHEMA")
    warehouse_name = os.getenv("WAREHOUSE")


    def get_data(sql_query: str, params: Tuple[str, str]=None) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """
        Get data from database as a DataFrame
        :param sql_query:
        :return: pd.DataFrame
        """
        snowflake.connector.paramstyle='numeric'
        conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
            user=snowflake_user,
            password=snowflake_password,
            account=snowflake_account,
            database=database_name,
            schema=schema_name,
            warehouse=warehouse_name,
        )
        cur = conn.cursor()
        try:
            cur.execute(sql_query, params)
            all_rows = cur.fetchall()
            field_names = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
            cur.get_results_from_sfqid(cur.sfqid)
            task_logger.info(f"The following was the query executed:\n{cur.query}")
        finally:
            cur.close()
        conn.close()
        df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows)
        if len(df):
            df.columns = field_names
        return df
```

So, I know the basic of how to use the numeric/qmark binding.
In other words, we need to declare `snowflake.connector.paramstyle='numeric'` before connect(). Also, execute takes two parameters; one is a query, the other numeric/qmark parameters in string.

With this, if I write the following query, I get SQL Compilation error, like  `SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position X unexpected ':'.` I get the same error if I write `database.:1.table`

```
        query = (
            "SELECT * "
            "FROM :1.shema.table"
        )
        params = ('my_database')
        df = get_data(query, params)
```

In contrast, the following is fine. The query gets sent to the database and the cursor returns the result.

```
        query = (
            "SELECT :1 "
            "FROM database.shema.table"
        )
        params = ('*')
        df = get_data(query, params)
```

Why can't I use the `:N` notation in front of the period?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to parametrize table name [IDENTIFIER/TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal) must be used:

```
query = (
        "SELECT * "
        "FROM IDENTIFIER(:1)"
)
params = ('my_database.schema.table')
df = get_data(query, params)
```

In this particular scenario, where `schema.table` is constant, alternative is to set the correct database at connection level and refer to objects using two part name.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know this. Thank you so much for teaching me this IDENTIFIER thingy!